# Prove $z + 1/z = 2 \cos(α) ⇒ z^n + 1/z^n = 2 \cos(nα)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Please prove $z + 1/z = 2 \cos(α) ⇒ z^n + 1/z^n = 2 \cos(nα)$

Comment: This is quite simple to conclude using [euler's form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Comment: Hint: $z = cis(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S_n = z^n + z^{-n}\implies S_n = \left(z+ z^{-1}\right)S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}=2\cos \alpha\cdot S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}$, and from this a strong induction proof can be used to establish the said identity.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $z + 1/z = 2 \cos α$ as a quadratic equation $z^2 - 2 z\cos α+1=0$ and solve to get $z=e^{\pm i \alpha}$. Then

$$ z^n + 1/z^n = e^{i n\alpha} + e^{-i n\alpha} = 2 \cos(nα)$$